Undefined name 'authToken'. Try correcting the name to one that is defined, or defining the name
I have defined the name 'authToken' in Products.dart and imported it.
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:my_shop/providers/product.dart';

class Products with ChangeNotifier {
  List<Product> _items = [];

  final String authToken;
  Products(this.authToken, this._items);

  //var _showFavoritesOnly = false;
  List<Product> get items {
    // if (_showFavoritesOnly) {
    //   return _items.where((prodItem) => prodItem.isFavorite).toList();
    // }
    return [..._items];
  }

  List<Product> get favoriteItems {
    return _items.where((prodItem) => prodItem.isFavorite).toList();
  }

but here I have this error at the end of the URL address:
var url = Uri.parse(
        'https://flutter-update-ced0c-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app/products/$id.json?auth=$authToken');

and here is my code:
error for authToken is Undefined name 'authToken'.
Try correcting the name to one that is defined, or defining the name.
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:my_shop/providers/products.dart';

class Product with ChangeNotifier {
  final String id;
  final String title;
  final String description;
  final double price;
  final String imageUrl;
  bool isFavorite;

  Product({
    required this.id,
    required this.title,
    required this.description,
    required this.price,
    required this.imageUrl,
    this.isFavorite = false,
  });

  void _setFavValue(bool newValue) {
    isFavorite = newValue;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  Future<void> toggleFavoritestatus(String token) async {
    final oldstatus = isFavorite;
    isFavorite = !isFavorite;
    notifyListeners();
    var url = Uri.parse(
        'https://flutter-update-ced0c-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app/products/$id.json?auth=$authToken');
    try {
      final response = await http.patch(url,
          body: json.encode(
            {'isFavorite': isFavorite},
          ));
      if (response.statusCode >= 400) {
        _setFavValue(oldstatus);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      _setFavValue(oldstatus);
    }
  }
}


Can you show where you are defining authToken?

`import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:my_shop/providers/product.dart';
class Products with ChangeNotifier {
List _items = [];
final String authToken;
Products(this.authToken, this._items);
//var _showFavoritesOnly = false;
List get items {
// if (_showFavoritesOnly) {
//   return _items.where((prodItem) => prodItem.isFavorite).toList();
// }
return [..._items];
}`

Can you update you question with it, here is not readable?

authToken is a member of the Products class, so you can access it only from an instance of the Products class.
final products = Products('my_auth_token', []);
print(products.authToken); // result: 'my_auth_token'


so how can I use authToken at the end of URL address in Product class and file?

@Toorajrezaei If your want Products to store the authToken then provide the Products instance to the Product, then you will be able to access the token. Otherwise you may create a service responsible for the fetch, and keep the token inside, then get that service where you need it.

can you teach me how?
